# Use OR clause instead AND in django-filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm working with the django-filter + django rest framework. I want to search a term with the OR clause. I have this filter:

```py
class ItemFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = filters.CharFilter(field_name="name")
    barcode = filters.CharFilter(field_name="barcode")

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['name', 'barcode']
```

when I send a query param like https://url?barcode=q&name=q django-filter searchs:

```sql
SELECT * FROM item where name = 'q' AND barcode = 'q'
```

How can I configure to search?:

```sql
SELECT * FROM item where name = 'q' OR barcode = 'q'
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the options would be using [`SearchFilter`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) in your view to filter on multiple fields:

```
from rest_framework import filters

class YourView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ...
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['name', 'barcode']
```

And then use `search` keyword in url query params:
`https://url?search=q`